# ¿Cómo puedo unir una palabra con caracteres separados dentro de una lista?

Tags: python

¿Cómo puedo concatenar los caracteres de esta lista?

```
separado = ["h","o","l","a"]
```

para que resulte igual a:

```
junto = ["hola"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pues la solución sería la siguiente:

```
separado = ["h","o","l","a"]
junto = ["".join(separado)]
```

Lo que está ocurriendo en cada línea es lo siguiente:

1. Creo una lista con elementos, este caso con string.
2. Utilizo la función join() que me devuelve una string con los elementos que contiene la lista separados por "". Para dejarlo más claro pongo otro ejemplo usando el join().

---

Ejemplo

```
lista = ['elemento1', 'elemento2']
junto = ";".join(lista)
```

En tal caso, "junto" es igual a --> "elemento1;elemento2"

Comment: muchas gracias, pero ¿podrías aclarar exactamente que esta ocurriendo con esas instrucciones?

Comment: @antoniooo0 hecho